# How to create a Grails HAL converter

Tags: grails, converters, hateoas

I know there is a HalJsonRenderer but i wonder if there would be a way to have something like the JSON converter in order to be able to do something like:

```
render MyObject as HAL
```

That "as" operator ... how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more clear what's happening with `render ... as JSON` if you add in the optional parentheses:

```
render(foo as JSON)
```

The render method has a few overloads and one of them accepts JSON, so the tricky part is `foo as JSON`.

Groovy makes it straightforward to overload operators by pairing every operator with a method that actually does the work. The `==` operator is implemented by calling the `equals` method (or `compareTo` if the class implements `Comparable`, the `<<` operator calls `leftShift`, etc. [This archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150102195637/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) has a good table of operators and their corresponding methods (the Groovy site was significantly overhauled recently and this page seems to have been lost in the shuffle).

`as` isn't technically an operator, but it's treated similarly. If you add an `asType` method, it will be invoked to give the class an opportunity to convert itself to the requested type:

```
Object asType(Class c) { ... }
```

The way that Grails wires up `as JSON` and `as XML` is rather convoluted, but the important part involves adding an `asType` method to all controllers (in addition to `render`, `redirect`, `getParams` (and the corresponding `params` property), etc.) This method then does the conversion to JSON or XML, or does a traditional cast/conversion if the target class isn't JSON or XML.

I think it would be more work than it's worth to support this directly, so if it were me I'd create a method in a service that does the work of converting supported types to HAL and render that, something like

```
class SomeService {
   String asHal(foo) {
      ...
   }
}
```

and then you can call it from your controllers:

```
class SomeController {

   def someService

   def anAction() {
      ...
      def foo = ...
      render someService.asHal(foo)
   }
}
```

That's not quite as convenient as `render as HAL`, but it's not much more work and has the benefit of being less magical.

To support `render foo as HAL` you would need to add an `asType` method to whatever class `foo` is, or do something similar to what Grails does for JSON and XML. Adding an `asType` method is probably impractical, especially if you want to support multiple types, and more so if those types are pre-existing classes like ArrayList. You could implement the `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.Converter` interface like the JSON and XML classes do (looking at the support code, you actually need to extend `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.AbstractConverter`), and create the associated support classes that would do the conversion (this was all designed to be extensible, although I don't think I've seen anyone do it). That would be interesting and probably a good learning experience, but as I said - way more work than it's worth given how simple the more direct implementation is.